# Configuring a DELL storage array with both controllers set to the same address

Tags: command-line-interface, storage-area-network, dell, dell-powervault

I've gotten hold of a used Dell PowerVault MD1000 with two MD3000i (aka AMP01) controllers, both of which are configured to the same address. However my attempts to configure them - or indeed perform any action, even "Blink" - fail with "Error connecting to the array management port(s). Please check the management port(s) to verify they are accessible". Additionally, while controller 0 reports status "Optimal", controller 1 reports status "ServiceMode", which I presume indicates an error.

Here's what I've accomplished so far:

- Get Dell Modular Disk Configuration Utility to identify both ports by connecting the Mgmt port of controller 1 and one of the data port of controller 0 to the network
- Get an interactive telnet session on the embedded VxWorks by following the instructions [here](https://www.orangecomputers.com/node/?command=kb&docid=30), and having done that -

  - Reset the password using `clearSYMbolPassword`
  - Dump the existing configuration using `netCfgShow`
  - Invoke `sysWipe`. However, it exits immiediately printing the message below. I presume the problem is with controller 1 being in service mode. On controller 0 I get:

`-> sysWipe
  Executing sysWipe. Boards will reboot on completion.
  03/27/18-14:58:39 (GMT) (tShellRem1): WARN:

  symbol::ControllerInServiceModeException Line 613 File samSymbol.cc
  value = 201459792 = 0xc020850`

Is there a way I can configure the IP addresses, other than getting hold of a dedicated Dell DB9 - PS2 cable?

Can I completely disable controller1 and just use controller 0, which appears to be in better shape? Unfortunately simply pulling out controller 1 doesn't help.

I'm attaching a screenshot from the Dell utility that depicts the configuration. Should I have been able to see the disks here?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Disconnect/unplug one controller, change the ip address of the connected/plugged in controller, reconnect/plug in the disconnected controller?

Comment: Already tried that before, and re-tried again now with one data port connected. the problems are as before both ``sysWipe`` and any action I try from the Modular Disk Configuration Utility fail as they did before.

Comment: Swapping the two controller cards revealed that the "ServiceMode" issue is specific to the slot and not to the card.

By removing all disks I was able to complete sysWipe.

Comment: Side note, if you ever need that serial cable and don't have one on hand, I posted the pinout for DIY-ers here: https://www.dell.com/community/PowerVault/Dell-part-for-MD1000-MD3000-debug-password-reset-cable/m-p/3087501/highlight/true#M15136

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to access my disk array using the full PowerVault Modular Storage Manager utility. I wasn't able to detect my array from Modular Storage Manager previously, so I must have done something right...